# save values into database Django

Tags: python, django, database, forms

Hi i am relatively new to Django. I have a timesheet for user to enters the details, when the submit button is chosen, the data in those filled-up fields will be saved into the Database. But i have no idea why mine doesnt work. As the values will be saved then it will be retrieved and be displayed in a table from in another html file.

**timesheet.html**

```
{% extends 'hrfinance/base.html' %}
{% block title %} Timesheet {% endblock %}
{% block link %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'hrfinance/css/timesheet.css' %}"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    /*to ensure that all the textbox and checkbox have been filled before users can submit*/
    function validation() {
        /*ensure start date has been entered*/
        if (!$('#studentid').val().trim()) {
            alert('Please fill in student ID field');
        }
        /*ensure start date has been entered*/
        if (!$('#studentname').val().trim()) {
            alert('Please fill in student name field');
        }
        /*ensure start date has been entered*/
        if (!$('#sdate').val().trim()) {
            alert('Please fill in start date field');
        }
        /*ensure end date has been entered*/
        if (!$('#edate').val().trim()) {
            alert('Please fill in end date field');
        }
        /*ensure checkbox has been ticked*/
        if (!$('#agree').is(':checked')) {
            alert('Please indicate that you have satisfied all the requirements');
        }
        else{
            console.log('ok')
      }
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="sub-bar">
    <p>Submit Timesheet</p>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<form onsubmit="return validation()">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="sub-content">
            <div>
                <p>Student ID: {{timesheet.studentID}}</p>
                <input id="sid" type="field" name="studentid">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sub-content">
            <div>
                <p>Student Name: {{timesheet.studentName}}</p>
                <input id="sname" type="field" name="studentname">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sub-content">
            <div>
                <p>Start Date: {{timesheet.startDate}}</p>
                <input id="sdate" type="date" name="startdate">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="sub-content">
            <div>
                <p>End Date: {{timesheet.endDate}}</p>
                <input id="edate" type="date" name="enddate">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div class="end-content">
        <div class="center-align">
            <div class="checklist">
                <p>By checking this box I agree that I have satisfied all requirements to continue receiving my scholarship
            allowance.</p>
                <input id="agree" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" class="tick-att">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="align-right">
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="submit" >
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</from>
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def timesheet(request):
return render(request, 'hrfinance/timesheet.html')
```

**models.py**

```
#consists of all the details in the timesheet
class Timesheet(models.Model):
studentID = models.CharField("Student ID", max_length=8, primary_key=True, default="")
studentName = models.CharField("Student Name", max_length=500, default="")
startDate = models.DateField("Start Date", max_length=8)
endDate = models.DateField("End Date", max_length=8)

def __str__(self):
    return self.studentID
```

Comment: Is that all in your views.py??

Comment: @FazilZaid yes...

Comment: Please have a look in this link ...https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/

Comment: First thing first, get to know how to get form input data in django views. As of now, leave about javascript validation

Comment: I don't think you even need JS validation, if you set field in the model to be required.

Comment: I'd suggest to you to go through official [Django polls tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/) as it contains barebones of what you need to know about databases and saving data from forms to them. You need to setup a database in ``settings.py``, and then in view to process a form by catching data from ``request``, and then using a ``save()`` method on your form.

Answer (score 1):

As Fazil already said please take a look into the documentation. But to give you a little help for the start: 
What you are missing is the form validation in your `views.py` like:

```
def timesheet(request):
    user = request.user 
    form = yourform(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        ....
        form.save()
    context = {
     'form':form,
     }
  return render(request, 'hrfinance/timesheet.html',context)
```

the `form.save` command saves your form into the db.

Your `<form>` tag is missing the method! (it should be POST).

I would suggest to follow a tutorial (the one from the django docs or any other) so you have an Idea how things work.

**In generell:** 
The shorter your question (especially the Code) the more likely someone is willing to read it. Things like `"<br>"` should be cut out. Nobody cares for the style of your form. Your JS Part should be cut out as well since it is irrelevant for the question.